# Where to find the associated tag numbers for the quickfix variables?

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I have the documentation for all fields in quickfix http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html.

However, there is no indication of what integer tags each field corresponds to. I have an idea of a few fields from examples I have found, such as

```
import quickfix as fix
order = fix.Message()

quantity = 100
order.setField(38, quantity)
```

Can anyone point me to some documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FIX protocol standard website](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/), particularly [FIXimate](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/), has all that you need to identify tag numbers and message layouts. There are also some example ROEs and other help and FIX standards information available there.